# Any shortcut to get ratio by multiple rows/columns key value matching in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have agricultural data with its world statistics, I am trying to get a percentage of each commodity's respective attributes to its world statistics. I am thinking of possible easier manipulation for this. I tried my way to getting division by column-wise, but I feel like key values matching for the columns and get division gonna be correct. Can anyone point me out what is the easiest way to get division by conditional key values matching in the columns? any thoughts?

**minimal data**:

here is the [minimal data on public gist](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/865dce78c50185d0932776a28fa8308e)

**my current attempt**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('minimal_data.csv')

allCommods= df['commodity'].unique().tolist()
df_notALL = df[~(df['country']=='World')]
df_wrld = df[(df['country']=='World')]
ctyList_notALL = df_notALL['country'].unique().tolist()
ctyList_wrd = df_wrld['country'].unique().tolist()
yrsList = df['year'].unique().tolist()

s=''
for i,j,k in zip(allCommods,ctyList_notALL, yrsList):
      s += '{}=="{}"&'.format(i,j, k)

w=''
for m,n,l in zip(allCommods, ctyList_wrd, yrsList):
    w += '{}=="{}"&'.format(m,n, l)
```

in above code, I tried to do key-value matching over the multiple columns first do division as follow:

```
df.div(df_wrld, axis=0).applymap(lambda x: f'{x * 100:.2f}%')
```

but I have the wrong computation, It seems my way of key-value matching over the multiple columns is not right, and manipulating the above data is not efficient. How can I make this work? Is there any straightforward way to get division for this data?

**concrete goal**:

I want to get the percentage ratio of each commodity's attribute to its world total.
 for example, the production rate of `Barley`, `Corn`, `Wheat` for each country over the years.

easy toy computation like:

`Corn_ production_rate_australia_2010 =  Corn_production_australia_2010/Corn_production_world_2010`

I want to get a list of dataframe, where each dataframe can have a percentage of each attribute (such as production, consumption, imports, exports) by year along the country wise. How to make this sort of operation easier in pandas? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
# compute the total production by commodity and country
new_df = (df.groupby(['commodity','country','year'])
            [['production','imports','exports']].sum()
            .unstack('commodity')
        )

# compute the contribution by dividing the `World` production
new_df.div(new_df.loc['World']).drop('World')
```

Output:

```
                   production                      ...   exports                    
commodity              Barley      Beef      Corn  ...      Oats      Pork     Wheat
country       year                                 ...                              
Argentina     2010   0.024047  0.044305  0.029666  ...  0.003160  0.000166  0.071362
              2011   0.033761  0.043117  0.023069  ...  0.006318  0.000143  0.081989
              2012   0.038677  0.044310  0.030035  ...  0.000967  0.000137  0.025712
              2013   0.032892  0.047414  0.025316  ...  0.000853  0.000143  0.013560
              2014   0.020473  0.044775  0.028125  ...  0.000851  0.000143  0.032280
...                       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
United States 2016   0.029606  0.191991  0.341164  ...  0.020602  0.284109  0.155863
              2017   0.021794  0.195829  0.343577  ...  0.014039  0.307980  0.135117
              2018   0.024091  0.196168  0.324269  ...  0.010818  0.315571  0.146805
              2019   0.023717  0.200977  0.312752  ...  0.012104  0.301393  0.148218
              2020        NaN  0.203120       NaN  ...       NaN  0.311118       NaN

[66 rows x 18 columns]
```

Comment: I think this is not correct computation, I want to get by year, like 2010 barely production rate, import, consumption, and so on. I think I clarified my intention quite clearly.

Comment: actually we don't need `world`. Looks like we need to loop through the columns like `import`, `production`, `export`. Can we improve the solution? Thanks

Comment: is there any way I could cast output multi-index dataframe into list of dataframe? thanks

Comment: You could do, for example: `new_df.loc['Argentina', 'production']`. The pair can be extracted with `get_level_values`.

Comment: thanks, I mean is that possible to programmatically do this easily? any tricks for this?

Comment: I think I could do like this: `for x, y in new_df.groupby(level=0):
    print(y)` but this is not completely correct, any idea?